# I have my data in postgres database. Sample data and required output should look like below

Tags: excel, postgresql, excel-formula, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3dGN.png)

I am having a very hard time in figuring this out. Can some one please look at the picture and provide a solution.
Please don't give a solution that involves coding in any scripting languages because I am not a programming guy.
I want to solve this through sql query(postgres) or using excel formulas in excel.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have postgres to test (so this may not be perfect). This solution assumes an `opening_id` has no more than two `locations`

```
Select 
t1.opening_id
Case when t2.Num >1 THEN 
CONCAT(t1.location,' | ',t2.location)
ELSE t1.location END as location
,AVG(t1.days_open,t2.days_open) as days_open
,t1.age_band
from table t1
INNER JOIN(
           Select 
           opening_id
           ,location
           ,AVG(days_open)
           ,COUNT(distinct location) as Num
           from table
           Group by opening_id
                   ,location
           )t2
ON t1.opening_id=t2.opening_id
Group by 
        t1.opening_id
       ,t2.Num
       ,CONCAT(t1.location,'|',t2.location)
       ,t1.location
       ,t1.age_band
```